# SVN checkout using https Error

Tags: svn, https, apache2, svn-checkout, ubuntu-8.04

I'm setting up `Qebek` using the instructions and tool versions as given in its 
paper [Click to see the link](https://www.honeynet.org/sites/default/files/files/KYT-Qebek-final_v1.pdf)

An error occurs when svn checkout using https is executed. The error is as follows:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~$ svn co https://projects.honeynet.org/svn/sebek/virtualization/qebek/trunk/ qebek
svn: PROPFIND request failed on '/svn/sebek/virtualization/qebek/trunk'
svn: PROPFIND of '/svn/sebek/virtualization/qebek/trunk': SSL negotiation failed: SSL error: tlsv1 alert internal error (https://projects.honeynet.org)
```

I've exhausted all the possible solutions (configuring virtualhost *:443 in apache2, opening 443 port, deleting ~/.svn file) that I could find but none has solved the above problem.
Please help me if any one knows how to resolve this error.

***On side note:*** Ive also used 'svn co' command using http and it works successfully. Output is

```
Checked out revision 66
```

But the next command gives following error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~/qebek$ sudo chmod +x configure texi2pod.pl
chmod: cannot access `texi2pod.pl': No such file or directory
```

I might be wrong but I think svn checking via http and not https has got to do something with this 'texipod.pl' file. 
So please tell me what exactly is wrong?